# position absolute full width if necessary

Tags: html, css, css-position, line-breaks

I have a div with "position: absolute" and a title inside. If the title is long, a break line is automatically applied even though the div width may increase.

I set the property max-width: 100% so that the text is added to the line only when we reach 100%.
Unfortunately, the text breaks at random.

Here are the properties of the absolute div:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 1px);
```

[The current rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWFZQ.png)

Do you have a solution ?
Sorry for my english, i am working to improve it

Comment: Do you want the white box to get increase along the text? So if text is long the width should also expand?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We may need to see the "whole picture" to solve the problem, what are all the styles applied to the text? What is your HTML structure?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `display: flex` for your div. By the way `position: absolute` doesn't work with what I have suggested. Or you can try making your text in the div float and your div should have `overflow: hidden`.